# Wicket redirect: how to pass on parameters and keeps URLs "pretty"?

Tags: java, redirect, wicket, friendly-url

Consider a Wicket WebPage that redirects to another page (based on some logic omitted from here):

```
public class SomePage extends WebPage {
    public SomePage(PageParameters parameters) {
        setResponsePage(AnotherPage.class);
        setRedirect(true);
    }
}
```

I need to pass on the PageParameters to that other page, and this seems to be the way to do that:

```
setResponsePage(new AnotherPage(parameters));
```

However, when creating a new Page object like this, I end up at an URL such as `/?wicket:interface=:1::::` instead of the clean `/another`. AnotherPage is defined as:

```
@MountPath(path = "another")
public class AnotherPage extends WebPage {
    // ...
}
```

(Where MountPath is from org.wicketstuff.annotation.mount package.)

So, my questions are:

- Some other way to pass on the params?
- Some way to keep the URL pretty? Is the above a Wicket Stuff specific limitation instead of core Wicket?

#### Update

Heh, turns out *any* of the suggested approaches work, and **also** what I originally tried — `setResponsePage(new AnotherPage(parameters))` — as long as I remove `setRedirect(true)`. The URL does stay the same (path to SomePage) in that case, and **I just realised** I really should have mentioned right from the start that it's okay if it does (as long as it's "pretty" and the parameters are passed)!

The page ("SomePage") dispatches requests, based on query params, to a couple of possible result pages that look different but that are accessed through the same url. I tried to formulate the question as generic and minimalist as possible, but that went awry as I left out relevant info. :-/

Sorry if this ended up weird, unclear or useless for others. If you have a suggestion about renaming it, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the other setResponsePage method in Component is closer to what you want:

```
/**
 * Sets the page class and its parameters that will respond to this request
 * 
 * @param <C>
 * 
 * @param cls
 *            The response page class
 * @param parameters
 *            The parameters for this bookmarkable page.
 * @see RequestCycle#setResponsePage(Class, PageParameters)
 */
public final <C extends Page> void setResponsePage(final Class<C> cls, PageParameters parameters)
{
    getRequestCycle().setResponsePage(cls, parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope, just calling `getRequestCycle().setResponsePage(cls, parameters)` instead doesn't do it for me. Same thing happens as with [Tim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155591/wicket-redirect-how-to-pass-on-parameters-and-keeps-urls-pretty/4183641#4183641).

Comment: No, wait, it does work! I needed to remove `setRedirect(true)` from my code too. So +1. I'll investigate the other suggestions before accepting an answer.

Comment: Leaving out `setRedirect(true)` was enough to get what I *actually* wanted (see updated question), but I'll accept this, at least for now, because `getRequestCycle().setResponsePage(class, params)` is sort of what I was looking for (no need to create Page object yourself even if you want to pass parameters).

Answer (score 5):

seanizer has the right idea, but just for completeness, there are more options than `BookmarkablePageRequestTargetUrlCodingStrategy` and `HybridUrlCodingStrategy`:

- [`IndexedHybridUrlCodingStrategy`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.4.x/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/IndexedHybridUrlCodingStrategy.html)
- [`IndexedParamUrlCodingStrategy`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.4.x/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/IndexedParamUrlCodingStrategy.html)
- [`MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.4.x/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy.html)
- [`QueryStringUrlEncodingStrategy`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.4.x/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/QueryStringUrlCodingStrategy.html)

Answer (score 4):

I think the key phrase on [this reference page](http://wicketstuff.org/confluence/display/STUFFWIKI/wicketstuff-annotation) is this:

> The next step is to determine which URL encoding strategy to use. Unless one is explicity specified, the default used is `BookmarkablePageRequestTargetUrlCodingStrategy`. In the example above, the Terms page uses the default.

I think you need to mount another url coding strategy, probably something like [`HybridUrlCodingStrategy`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/HybridUrlCodingStrategy.html).

Edit: you probably just need to add this annotation to do that:

```
@MountMixedParam(parameterNames={"param1", "param2"})
```

Comment: Thanks! Quickly tested @MountMixedParam but it didn't seem to help (or I didn't use it correctly). But gotta dash now; I'll look into this tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry; turns out I failed to express what I actually wanted, because leaving out the redirect entirely actually achieves that (see updated question). Oh well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully been using this from an onClick handler, but not yet sure if it'll work from an constructor as well:

```
getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new BookmarkablePageRequestTarget(ReportPage.class, params));
```

Comment: I just tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work; at least not without some other changes too. (For me this yields an empty page, with the url becoming something like `/another/param1/value1/param2/value2`.)

Comment: As with [mfunk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155591/wicket-redirect-how-to-pass-on-parameters-and-keeps-urls-pretty/4183365#4183365), this *does* work after all, after removing `setRedirect(true)`. So +1; I'll investigate some more before deciding what to accept.