# Is there a way to pass hidden values in Wicket?

Tags: java, parameters, wicket

As described in [Wicket redirect: how to pass on parameters and keeps URLs "pretty"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155591/wicket-redirect-how-to-pass-on-parameters-and-keeps-urls-pretty), there are a variety of options for passing parameters in Wicket. However, all of the methods listed on that page use the URL to transmit parameter information.

Is there a class that's similar to [the PageParameters class](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.4.1/wicket-1.4.1-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/wicket/PageParameters.html) except that it hides the information it's transmitting? I don't care about bookmarkability, but I do care about URLs like

```
http://www.example.com/example.html?uniqueId=309308&superSecretValue=42
```

Comment: Do you want the URLs in the browser to be "pretty", or is it enough that the user can't understand them?

Comment: @Adrian, "pretty" would be nice, but isn't terribly important.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Installing a custom URL coding strategy](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/url-coding-strategies.html) is the way.

Note though that normally Wicket doesn't expose its internal state anyway, so you'll only need this for bookmarkable pages.

Comment: Most of those strategies make the URL prettier, but don't actually hide the information, which is the critical thing. But I'll accept this because it mentions [the `CryptedUrlWebRequestCodingStrategy` class](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.4.1/wicket-1.4.1-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/request/CryptedUrlWebRequestCodingStrategy.html). Unfortunately, it seems to be all-or-nothing; I can't pass `superSecretValue` in the background while keeping `nonSecretValue` unobfuscated in the URL.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus Of course you can, you just need to write your own coding strategy. But like I said, if your links are non-bookmarkable, there's nothing to hide in the first place.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus Although it would help if you showed a code sample of where these urls should typically originate from.