# Passing parameter as hidden in wicket

Tags: wicket-1.5

Please new in wicket wants to know how to pass value from wicket java page to an input field in its html page. (like if the java page is kachi.java and the html page is kachi.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read about wicket models and PageParameters on 
https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/

Comment: Similar question is asked before:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147040/is-there-a-way-to-pass-hidden-values-in-wicket